# Unit testing an aurelia custom element

Tags: unit-testing, aurelia

I'm testing a simple collapse custom element with view:

`<template>
    <button click.delegate="toggle()"></button>
    <div show.bind="collapsed">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>`

and view model:

`export class Collapse {
    collapsed: boolean;
    toggle() {
        this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
    }
}`

My test looks like that:

`it('should show content on flag change', done => {
        component.create(bootstrap).then(() => {
            const div = <Element> document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
            const style = window.getComputedStyle(div);

            expect(style.display).toBe('none');

            component.viewModel.toggle();

            setTimeout(() => {
                expect(style.display).toBe('block');
                done();
            }, 0);
        });
    });`

Can I get rid of the setTimeout in some way?

Answer (score 3):

```js
  it('should show content on flag change', done => {
    let div: HTMLDivElement;
    component.create(bootstrap)
      .then(() => {
        div = <HTMLDivElement>document.querySelector('div');
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
        expect(style.display).toBe('none');
        component.viewModel.toggle();
      })
      .then(() => {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
        expect(style.display).toBe('block');
      })
      .then(done);
    });
  });
```

Comment: It does not work. Only when wrapped in setTimeout works:
.then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
                expect(style.display).toBe('block');
            }, 0);
        })